# Solving $f(yf(x)+x/y)=xyf(x^2+y^2)$ over the reals

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(1)=1$ and for all real numbers $x$ and $y$ with $y \neq 0$,  $$f\Bigg (yf(x)+\frac{x}{y}\Bigg)=xyf(x^2+y^2)$$

This seems quite hard. $f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{x}, x\neq 0 \\ 0, x=0 \end{cases}$ works by inspection, as does $f(x)=0$ (though I'm not sure if this is legitimate. If we set $y=1$, we have $f(f(x)+x)=xf(x^2+1)$. If we set $x=1$, we have $f(\frac{y^2+1}{y})=yf(y^2+1)$. which seems to imply $f(f(x)+x)=f(\frac{x^2+1}{x})$. If I could show that $f$ is injective I could go further, but I'm stuck - subbing in other values doesn't really seem to lead anywhere either.

I believe this problem came from an Olympiad camp.

Comment: Are you sure it is $y\neq 1$ and not $y\neq 0$?

Comment: @RedundantAunt should be $y\neq 0$ - fixed, thanks!

Comment: The problem seems really hard to me! Are you sure that it has a nice solution or might there exist pathological solutions to this functional equation?

Comment: @RedundantAunt this question was shared to me - unfortunately, I can’t solve it either! (Hence why I’m asking)

Comment: My question was rather wether the source of the problem would guarantee it to have only ‘nice’ solutions (e.g. if the problem comes from an official exam), or if it potentially has pathological solutions (e.g. if it was constructed by a friend of yours).

Comment: @RedundantAunt My friend told me it came from an Olympiad camp, so I assume it should have a nice solution? I don't think they made this.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Solving for the implicit function $f\left(f(x)y+\frac{x}{y}\right)=xyf\left(x^2+y^2\right)$ and $f(1)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45260), and AOPS links https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h411400p2923354 ,  https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h148711 and https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h358223. And the original source https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/AMC/a-activities/a6-mosp/a6-1-mosparchives/2007-ma/mosptests.pdf (Problem 7.4)

Answer (score 5):

Here is one approach,

the equation $y f(x)+ \frac{x}{y}=x^2 + y^2$ for $x \neq 0$ does have at least one real root, since the equation is equivalent to a cubic equation. Denote this root by $\lambda$.

inputting $\lambda$ into the equation we find $f(x^2+y^2)=x \lambda f(x^2+y^2)$. Now, notice that $x^2+y^2 \neq 0$, if you can show that for some $\sigma$ that $f(\sigma)=0\, \iff \sigma =0$ then the result folllows since, then $\lambda = \frac{1}{x}$ and form the initial functional equation you would obtain $f(x)\lambda + \frac{x}{\lambda}=x^2+\lambda^2\, \implies f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$

Thus, the solution to the problem is found by asserting that you can prove that

> $f(\sigma)=0 \, \iff \sigma = 0$

The road to glory I belive requires analysis of the following relation

> $f(f(x)+x) = xf(x^2+1)$

Allows us to show that for $x \neq 0$ then $f(x)=0 \implies f(x^2+1)=0$ which implies $\exists\,$ a sequence $S_n \to \infty$ such that $f(S_n)=0$. For the following, assume $f$ is continuous.

Now, take $x^2+y^2=S_n$, the initial relation implies that
$$f\left(f(x)y+ \frac{x}{y}\right)=0\, \forall \,x^2+y^2=S_n$$

Now, for $y \to 0^+$ and $x>0$ one finds that $f(x)y+\frac{x}{y} \to \infty$ as $x \to \sqrt{S_n}$, thus $f$ takes zero values in the neighbourhood of $\infty$.

Since $f(y+\frac{1}{y}) = y f(1+y^2)\, \implies f(x)=-f(-x)\, \forall\, |x| \geq 2$ we find the same result in the neighbourhood of $- \infty$. Notice now that for $y>1$ that $y+\frac{1}{y} > 1+y^2$ one can translate the zeroes in the neighbourhood of $\infty$ until you reach $2$. So that

> $f(x)=0$ on $(-\infty, -2]\, \cup \, [2, \infty)$

Not sure where else to go from here, but this may provide a useful aid to a full solution.

Answer (score 4):

Summary: This solution shows that if a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(1)=1$ and $f\left(yf(x)+\frac{x}{y}\right)=xyf\left(x^2+y^2\right)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R},y\neq0$, then $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ for all $x\neq0$. **No additional assumptions on $f$ are necessary!**

Thanks @Sil for giving all these references! I meanwhile came up with a solution myself, and last but not least because not many solutions of this problem seem to be around, I would like to share mine.

Suppose $f$ is a solution to this functional equation and for $x,y\in\mathbb{R},\ y\neq0$ write $P(x,y)$ for the assertion $f\left(yf(x)+\frac{x}{y}\right)=xyf\left(x^2+y^2\right)$. Furthermore, we define $\mathcal{N}:=\{x>0\ |\ f(x)=0\}$, and assume that $\mathcal{N}\neq\emptyset$.

As @Kevin already pointed out, we have $\alpha\in\mathcal{N}\implies\alpha^2+1\in\mathcal{N}$, and in particular $\mathcal{N}$ is unbounded. Furthermore, $P(1,\alpha)$ gives also $\alpha\in\mathcal{N}\implies\alpha+\frac{1}{\alpha}\in\mathcal{N}$. Now, if $\alpha,\beta\in\mathcal{N}$ then
$$
P(\alpha,\beta):\quad f\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)=\alpha\beta f\left(\alpha^2+\beta^2\right)\\
P(\beta,\alpha):\quad f\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)=\beta\alpha f\left(\beta^2+\alpha^2\right)
$$
and thus $f\left(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\right)=f\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha}\right)$. Therefore, if $\alpha\in\mathcal{N}$ then
$$
f\left(\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)=f\left(\frac{\alpha+\frac{1}{\alpha}}{\alpha^2+1}\right)=f\left(\frac{\alpha^2+1}{\alpha+\frac{1}{\alpha}}\right)=f(\alpha)=0
$$
and thus also $\frac{1}{\alpha}\in\mathcal{N}$. This gives, together with the unboundedness of $\mathcal{N}$, the existence of $(\alpha_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathcal{N}^\mathbb{N}$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha_n=0$.

Now notice that for $x\neq 0$ and $\alpha\in\mathcal{N}$
$$
P(\alpha,\alpha^2 x):\quad f\left(\frac{1}{\alpha x}\right)=\alpha^3 x f\left(\alpha^4\left(x^2+\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\right)\right)\\
P(\frac{1}{\alpha}, x):\quad f\left(\frac{1}{\alpha x}\right)=\frac{x}{\alpha} f\left(x^2+\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\right)
$$
and thus $\alpha^4 f\left(\alpha^4\left(x^2+\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\right)\right)=f\left(x^2+\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\right)$ for all $x\neq 0$, or in more simple terms
$$
(*)\qquad\alpha^4 f(\alpha^4 z) = f(z) \quad\forall \alpha\in\mathcal{N},\ z>\frac{1}{\alpha^2}
$$
Now for a fixed $\alpha\in\mathcal{N}$ and $y>0$ let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $y>\max\{\frac{\alpha_n^2}{\alpha^4},\frac{\alpha_n^4}{\alpha^2},\alpha_n^2\}$, which exists as $(\alpha_n)\to 0$. Then
$$
\alpha^4 f(\alpha^4 y)=\frac{\alpha^4}{\alpha_n^4} \alpha_n^4 f\left(\alpha_n^4\frac{\alpha^4 y}{\alpha_n^4}\right)\overset{\frac{\alpha^4 y}{\alpha_n^4}>\frac{1}{\alpha_n^2}}{=}\frac{1}{\alpha_n^4}\alpha^4 f\left(\alpha^4\frac{y}{\alpha_n^4}\right)\overset{\frac{y}{\alpha_n^4}>\frac{1}{\alpha^2}}{=}\frac{1}{\alpha_n^4}f\left(\frac{y}{\alpha_n^4}\right)\overset{y>\alpha_n^2}{=}f(y).
$$
Thus we can strengthen $(*)$ and actually have
$$
(**)\qquad\alpha^4 f(\alpha^4 z) = f(z) \quad\forall \alpha\in\mathcal{N},\ z>0.
$$
In particular, for $z=\frac{1}{\alpha^2}$ we get $\alpha^4f(\alpha^2)=f\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\right)$. On the other hand, we see that as $1+\alpha^2,1+\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\in\mathcal{N}$, we have by again combining $P(1+\alpha^2,1+\frac{1}{\alpha^2})$ and $P(1+\frac{1}{\alpha^2},1+\alpha^2)$ that
$$
f(\alpha^2)=f\left(\frac{1+\alpha^2}{1+\frac{1}{\alpha^2}}\right)=f\left(\frac{1+\frac{1}{\alpha^2}}{1+\alpha^2}\right)=f\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\right)
$$
and thus, as $\alpha>0$ and $\alpha\neq 1$, we have $\alpha^4f(\alpha^2)=f\left(\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\right)=f(\alpha^2)\implies f(\alpha^2)=0$ so $\alpha^2\in\mathcal{N}$. But then also $\alpha^4\in\mathcal{N}$ which gives by $(**)$
$$
0=\alpha^4 f(\alpha^4)\overset{(**)}{=} f(1)=1,
$$
contradiction!

Therefore we conclude that $\mathcal{N}$ is empty, and as @Kevin already saw this gives $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ for all $x\neq 0$. As $P(0,y)$ gives $f(0)=0$, we have uniquely determined $f$, and we can verify easily that $f$ is indeed a solution of the equation at hand.

Answer (score 1):

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Some forms of the equation.}}$

If $\underline{x\not=0},$ then unknowns can be swapped. So
$$f\left(yf(x)+\dfrac xy\right) = xyf(x^2+y^2) = f\left(xf(y)+\dfrac yx\right),\tag1$$
with the partial cases
$$\begin{cases}
y=1,\quad f(f(x)+x) = xf(x^2+1) = f\left(x+\dfrac1x\right) \hspace{226mu}(2.1)\\[4pt]
y=x,\quad f(xf(x)+1) = x^2f(2x^2) \hspace{350mu}(2.2)\\[4pt]
\end{cases}$$
Denote
$$g(x) = xf(x)\tag3,$$
then from $(2)$ should
$$\begin{cases}
g(1+x^2) = g\left(x+\dfrac1x\right) \hspace{432mu}(4.1)\\[4pt]
g(g(x)+1) = \frac12g(2x^2)(g(x)+1)\hspace{370mu}(4.2)\\[4pt]
\end{cases}$$
Assume $g(x)$ continuous function.

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Corollaries from the formula (4.1).}}$

Using the relationships between the arguments in $(4.1)$ in the form of
\begin{cases}
L_{1,2}=1+x^2=\dfrac 12R(R\pm\sqrt{R^2-4})\\[4pt]
R_{1,2}=x+\dfrac1x = \pm\left(\sqrt {L-1}+\dfrac1{\sqrt{L-1}}\right),
\end{cases}
one can present equation $(4.1)$ in the forms of
\begin{cases}
g(x) = g\left(\dfrac 12x(x\pm\sqrt{x^2-4})\right)\hspace{382mu}(5.1)\\[4pt]
g(x) = g\left(\pm\left(\sqrt{x-1} + \dfrac1{\sqrt{x-1}}\right)\right).\hspace{330mu}(5.2)
\end{cases}
From $(5.2)$ should $g(1)=g(\pm\infty),$
$$g(\pm\infty)=1.$$
Also, formula $(5.2)$ allows to assign to each point of the interval $(1,2)$ the point of the interval $(2,\infty)$ with the same value of the function $g.$

At the same time, repeated recursive application of formula $(5.1)$ allows to prove that 
$$g(x)=1\quad \forall \quad x\in((-\infty,-2]\cup[2,\infty)).\tag6$$

$\color{brown}{\textbf{Corollaries from the formula (4.2).}}$

Let us consider such neighbour of the point $x=1,$ where $g(x)>0.$
Then the right part of the system $(4.2)$ can be presented in the form of
$$g(2x^2)(1+g(x)) = 2.\tag7$$
Applying $(7)$ for $x$ from $1$ to $+0$ and from $-2$ to $-0,$ easy to see that 
$g(x)=1.\tag8$

The value in the singular point $x=0$ can be defined immediately from the equaion $(1)$ and equals to zero.

Theerefore, the OP solution
$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0,\quad\text{if}\quad x=0\\[4pt]
\dfrac1x,\quad\text{otherwize}
\end{cases}$$
is the single non-trivial solution.

Comment: How do you conclude that $f(-y)=f(y)$ from $(1)$?

Comment: Also, how do you account for the solution $f=0$?

Comment: In fact, if $f$ is monotonic it is injective and then the fact that
$$f(yf(x)+\tfrac{x}{y})=xyf(x^2+y^2)=(-x)(-y)f((-x)^2+(-y)^2)=f(-yf(-x)+\tfrac{-x}{-y}),$$
shows that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$, directly contradicting $(2)$ unless $f=0$.

Comment: Also, I don't see immediately how you prove that $f$ is monotonic on these intervals; your observation partitions $(1,\infty)$ into infinite sequences on which $f$ is monotonic, but I don't see how this implies that $f$ is monotonic on the entire interval. The same for the interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Servaes Thanks! Fixed all.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:\textbf{R}\rightarrow\textbf{R}$, such that $f(1)=1$ and
$$
f\left(yf(x)+\frac{x}{y}\right)=xyf(x^2+y^2)\textrm{, }\forall (x,y)\in\textbf{R}\times\textbf{R}^{*}\tag 1
$$
Set $x=0$, $y=1$ in (1), then easily $f(0)=0$ (the case $f(0)\neq 0$ is trivial). For $y=1$ in (1) we get
$$
xf(x^2+1)=f(f(x)+x)\textrm{, }x\neq 0.\tag 2
$$ 
Also using the symmetry we get
$$
f\left(yf(x)+\frac{x}{y}\right)=f\left(xf(y)+\frac{y}{x}\right)\textrm{, }x,y\neq 0
$$
For $y=1$, we get
$$
f\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)=f(f(x)+x)\textrm{, }x\neq 0\tag 3
$$
Assume that $h(x,y)$ is a surface (function) such that 
$$
f(y+h(x,y))=f(x).\tag 4
$$
Note.

One choise of $h(x,y)$ is $h(x,y)=-y+x$ but may be there others. For example if $f(x)=x^2-x+1$, then $h(x,y)=x-y$ or $h(x,y)=1-x-y$.

We assume here that 
$$
f(x)=h\left(x+\frac{1}{x},x\right)\tag{4.1}
$$
From (4) with $x\rightarrow x+\frac{1}{x}$ we get 
$$
f\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)=f\left(y+h\left(x+\frac{1}{x},y\right)\right).
$$
Hence for $y=x$ in the above identity we get 
$$
f\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)=f\left(x+h\left(x+\frac{1}{x},x\right)\right)=f(x+f(x))
$$
Hence we can get (3). From (2) and (3) we get also
$$
xf(x^2+1)=f\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\tag 6
$$
Setting $x\rightarrow x^{-1}$ in (6)
$$
\frac{1}{x}f\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)=f\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)=xf(x^2+1).\tag 7
$$
Hence if we set $x^2\rightarrow x>0$ in (7), then
$$
f\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)=xf(x+1)\textrm{, for all }x>0.\tag 8
$$
Set also $x=y-1>0$ in (8), then 
$$
f\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)=(y-1)f(y)\textrm{, }y>1.
$$
With $y=1/w>1$ we get
$$
\frac{1}{1-w}f\left(\frac{1}{1-w}\right)=\frac{1}{w}f\left(\frac{1}{w}\right).
$$
Hence if $0<w<1$ and $g(w):=\frac{1}{w}f\left(\frac{1}{w}\right)$, then
$$
f(x)=x^{-1}g\left(x^{-1}\right)\textrm{, where }x>1\textrm{ and }g(1-w)=g(w)\textrm{, }0<w<1\tag 9
$$
The solution (9) satisfies (8),(7),(6), but for to holds (3) we get plus a new functional equation for $f(x)$ and this is (4.1).

Hence the general solution is
$$
f(x)=h\left(x+\frac{1}{x},x\right)\tag{11}
$$
with
$$
\frac{1}{x-1}h\left(x-1+\frac{1}{x-1},\frac{1}{x-1}\right)=\frac{1}{x}h\left(x+\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{x}\right)\tag{12}
$$
and $h(x,y)$ solution of 
$$
f(y+h(x,y))=f(x).\tag{13}
$$ 
An obvious solution of $(13)$ is $h(x,y)=x-y$, but it may exist and other solutions.